# gnuplot used defined function - is there comprehensive documentation?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to write a cumulative function (my version of gnuplot does NOT have smooth cumul option!)

But the documentation for user-defined functions is very limited. For example what does this do? The docs list it - but don't explain it?!

```
delta(t) = (t == 0)
```

Is there a more thorough explanation anywhere?

Comment: To those migrating these questions -- Why are you doing this?  In what way is SU a better SE site for this question than SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gnuplot, logical expressions evaluate to 1 or 0 as they do in C.  Your function above will return 1 if (and only if) the `t` you pass in equals 0 -- Otherwise it returns 0.

The documentation on `help operators` states:

> The operators in `gnuplot` are the same as the corresponding operators in the
>    C programming language, except that all operators accept integer, real, and
>    complex arguments, unless otherwise noted.  The ** operator (exponentiation)
>    is supported, as in FORTRAN.
>
> Parentheses may be used to change order of evaluation.

I'm not really sure how much additional information there is to say.  There is more help available for the various operators as well -- `help operator unary` or `help operator binary` ...

Also see `help user-defined` for a little more info on how to define functions and `help expressions` for help on how to write gnuplot expressions in general.